# read name of selected file

Tags: javascript, html

i use input(type="file") tag in one of my forms like this:

```
<span class="btn fileinput-button btn-success">
<span>select files</span>
<input type="file" id="fileupload" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
```

i want to read the selected file name in a another java script function.
i want to read the selected file name here in the java script function to use as a parameter:

```
var req="ajax/updatereguser.php?uname="+txtuname+"&avatar="+txtavatar+"& bdate="+txtbdate+"&sex="+txtsex+"&lang="+txtlang+"&country="+txtcountry+"&phone="+txtphone;
xmlhttp.open("GET",req,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

or read that and use as a parameter in the following code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="btncontinue" id="btncontinue" onClick="updateregusers(txtparameter)">Continue</button>
```

how can i do this? thanks

Comment: if there are more than 1 file then

Comment: you have set `multiple` in the file field so it allows selection of multiple files...

Comment: i know. but i didn't think it's important for read the selected file name. is it important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
var file = document.getElementById('fileupload');
var name;
if (file.files) { //file api is available
    name = file.files.length > 0 ? file.files[0].name : '';
} else {
    name = file.value.split('\\').pop();
}
```